# what does the function dentry_path_raw do

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Please explain this statement:

```
directory_path=dentry_path_raw(lower_dentry,buf,buflen);
```

also give an example of how does it work

What fields does `struct dentry` contain?
What does the `s_root` field point to?
What does the field `s_root` contain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check [the fields of dentry here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/dcache.h#L103). `dentry_path_raw` puts the full path of the directory entry from the root of the file system into the `buffer`. `s_root` [is a member of](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h#L1233) `super block` defined in `linux/fs.h` and is the root of the file system, which is a `dentry`.

Comment: thanks n pls explain s_root more. if abc = super_block->s_root; what information will abc contain.

Comment: pls explain that in statement- dir_path=dentry_path_raw(lower_dentry,buf,buflen); the path is stored in dir_path, but what' the use of parameters buf and buflen ??

Comment: buf contains the path, buflen is the length of the buffer, it looks like dir_path points to the end of the path in buffer

Comment: then what is the use of passing lower_dentry to the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *dentry_path_raw(struct dentry *dentry, char *buf, int buflen)
```

The above function returns full pathname from root of the file system into the buffer.Each field is explained as below.

@dentry-dentry of a file to lookup

@buf-buffer to store path to

@buflen-length of @buf

For more detail check fs/dcache.c file.